# PHP Extract function on array from a select *

Tags: php

I have a huge amounts of columns in an SQL database, and I need them all. Instead of specifying them in the select query, I just want to use a `SELECT *`.

The query runs fine, but I get undefined index errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: servername in
>   /var/www/backup/backupoverview.php on line 66

```
<?php
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
    extract($row);
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row["servername"]?></td>
        <td><?=$row["criticality"]?></td>
        <td><?=$row["actioned"]?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

My googling pointed me towards the extract function but that didn't seem to do anything.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you also posted the $result value

Comment: the `extract()` function is completely unnecessary here. The problem is that your row does not contain a field called `servername`. Check what it does contain by doind a `print_r($row)`

Comment: Is `servername` a field returned by your query? Looks like it's not a part of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since you're reading `$row['fieldname']`, you don't have to extract $row at all.

Then the actual error: If you use `select *` you will get all columns, but apparently `servername` is not one of them. That's what the error is telling you.

Since you seem to be certain that such a field exists (we don't have the query, so I'll have to take your word), please note that array indexes are *case sensitive*, so if the column is named `SERVERNAME` in the database, you cannot find it, because it is returned in the case it has in the database. That's one advantage of specifying exact columns instead of `*`: you know which columns you select, and you can specify their case.

Actually, using `select *` is commonly regarded as bad practise, so maybe you can reconsider specifying the exact columns you need.

Answer (score 2):

A Notice: Undefined index: servername means **there is no index** `servername` in the $row array.

You have to define such a field in the table you are querying first

While `extract()` has actually nothing to do with absent indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the notice, you probably need to take a closer look at the field-names, because all it's saying is that there is no `servername` index in `$row`, which suggests there is no `servername` field in the table
Try `var_dump(array_keys($row));` inside the loop, and correct your typo, or just check your tbl.

In addition: `mssql_fethc_array` fetches the results as a *numerically indexed* array *and* an associative array by default, since you're only after the assoc array, I'd suggest using [`mssql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-assoc.php) instead, or `mssql_fetch_object`, if objects don't scare you ;)
From the docs:

> Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead. mssql_fetch_assoc() is equivalent to calling mssql_fetch_array() with MSSQL_ASSOC for the optional second parameter.

So either:

```
while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)){}
//or
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result, MSSQL_ASSOC)){}
```

Will result in `$row` being the assoc array *only*
What you have now works, too, but I consider it to be pointless (you don't need the numeric indexes, because you're not using them).
Though seeing as you're only building a table with the values:

```
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result,MSSQL_NUM))
{
    echo vprintf('<tr>'. str_repeat('<td>%s</td>', count($row)).'</tr>', $row);
}
```

Does just that anyway, but there's no risk of typo's in the array-keys.
Note: Be careful with one-liners like I used here, in this case the statement isn't too long, and still pretty readable, but if you use stuff like this too much, co-workers will curse and suggest you to go and write mindfuck instead

Comment: Incorrect. Citing from the manual: "mssql_fetch_array() is an extended version of mssql_fetch_row(). In addition to storing the data in the numeric indices of the result array, it also stores the data in associative indices, using the field names as keys."

Comment: Right and Wrong, mssql_fetch_array() is an extended version of mssql_fetch_row(). In addition to storing the data in the numeric indices of the result array, it also stores the data in associative indices, using the field names as keys (php.net).

Comment: @YourCommonSense: Right you are, I was expecting the same behaviour as `mysql_fetch_array`... edited my answer some bit, will edit further

Comment: @kander: So it turns out to be. I've corrected the mistake, and addressed _the actual issue_ of the non-existent index

Comment: Nice solution for building a table; will keep it in mind! Just wondering about the "table? really?" comment.. nothing wrong with using tables, as long as you use them for (duh) tabular data, which this seems to be ;)

Comment: @kander: thanks for pointing out my mistake. It's been a while since I got a -1 _with_ a comment that explained _why_, so I was able to learn from my mistake.I'll remove the tbl comment, and add a note that this kind of `echo+vprintf+str_repeat+count` code should be kept to a minimum, because co-workers will hate you for it in the end ;)

Comment: You're welcome - and glad to see you taking it well. Few things bug me as much as getting -1'ed without an explanation of why, so I try not to do unto others what I wish not done unto myself.

Answer (score 1):

Even better

```
<?php
echo '
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" class="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Servername</th>
        <th>Criticality</th>
        <th>Actioned</th>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$row['servername'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['criticality'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['actioned'].'</td>
    </tr>';
}

echo '
</table>';
```

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the documentation for the extract function, you'll see that what it does is extract the values of an array into the current scope. So, if you have an array:

array('servername' => 'localhost', 'criticality' => 1, 'actioned' => 'no);

What this will do is create $servername, $criticality and $actioned. Not what you want.

Make sure that the column names match (case sensitive!) what you have between the square brackets.